# Darth Maul Timeline Inconsistencies

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-rebels, darth-maul

So the original Star Wars movies had Darth Maul killed in the fight with the Obi-Wan and Qui-Gon. We later find out that he survived, which was depicted in Star Wars The Clone Wars animated series, and then he makes an appearance as the leader of the Crimson Dawn criminal syndicate in the Han Solo movie.

The inconsistency is that Star Wars Rebels had Darth Maul killed for good in a duel with an aged Obi-Wan, which means this happened sometime before Obi-Wan trained Luke, and surely after Han Solo movie. Is this right?

Some timelines don't fit if this is the right chronological order.

Comment: The 2nd duel with Kenobi happens a few months (a year at most) before Episode IV, while the Han Solo movie never existed, so problem solved!

Comment: More seriously, the Han Solo movie happens when Solo is quite young, so many years before Rebels and Episode IV.

Comment: Killed for good. Lol. You dear sweet naive child.

Comment: I don't think there will be a second resurrection of Darth Maul. He had an interesting story and it would just be ruined by having him come back again.

Comment: @Loki I'm still confused about the position on the timeline of Solo - Han is on his way to do a job he's heard about for Jabba the Hutt at the end of Solo - if he was quite young, then he managed to avoid bounty hunters for many years before Ep IV - (different Andrew)

Comment: “the original Star Wars movies had Darth Maul killed” — did you just refer to the prequels as “the original Star Wars movies”?? You get out of here right now.

Comment: The Jabba job mentioned at the end of Solo may not be the one that goes bad and therefore causes Jabba to pursue Han in episode 4 and beyond.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Definitely not the first job, if you consider this scene to be canonical : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rR0b57coZFk

Comment: @Andrew Han had already been a smuggler for years in Ep. IV, where it was implied that he knew Jabba quite well (there's a scene added by Lucas in the latest versions where Han steps (!) on Jabba at some point).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you have the timelines a little confused.

- Maul's unfortunate bisection in *Phantom Menace* takes place in [32 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Episode_I_The_Phantom_Menace#cite_note-Leland_Chee_Date_Tweet-0).
- Maul re-appears during the *Clone Wars* era in [22 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_Wars#cite_note-GA-8)
- His appearance in *Solo: A Star Wars Story* takes place in [10 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story#cite_note-Official_Guide-13)

and

- His death in *Star Wars: Rebels* occurs eight years after that in (approx) [2 BBY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Rebels#cite_note-Insider_148:_Launch_Pad-26).

Comment: So all the events from Star Wars Rebels take place between Han Solo movie and Rogue One movie, which ends right where Episode IV begins?

Comment: @Andrew - Yup. The Clone Wars lasted from 22 BBY to 19 BBY and ended with the decapitation (literally in some cases) of the Separatist Alliance on Mustafar, the destruction of the Jedi Order and the creation of the Empire (RoTS). *Solo* takes place about ten years after the Empire took control of Corellia and ten years before Rogue One/A New Hope.